# tratar cadenas rellenadas caracter a caracter en c

Tags: c, string

estoy acostumbrado a otros lenguajes. Ahora estoy en C.
He rellenado una "cadena" caracter a caracter y al imprimirla no aparece nada, no sé si es por el terminador nulo o por qué motivo. Agradecería ayuda.
Simplemente quiero eliminar de una ruta completa el path y quiero quedarme con el archivo y la extensión del archivo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char linea[50]="c:\\pepe\\resul.exe";
char nombrefich[50]="";
int x,cantidad,i;

void main()
{
    printf("Cadena inicial: %s\n",linea);
    x=strlen(linea);
    cantidad=1;
    do {
        x--;
        cantidad++;
    } while (linea[x]!='\\');

    x++;
    i=1;
    for(x=x;x<strlen(linea);x++)
    {
        //printf("%c",linea[x]);
        nombrefich[i]=linea[x];
        i++;
    }
    nombrefich[i]='\0';
    printf("Resultado final: %s\n",nombrefich);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo bien qué hace el programa (¿por qué el primer bucle `do`? ¿es para saltarse todo lo que haya hasta el último `\\`?) En cualquier caso veo un error de concepto. Los índices de los arrays comienzan en 0 y no en 1.

Comment: Por cierto que para quedarse sólo con el nombre del archivo puedes usar `basename()`, por ejemplo: `char *result=basename(linea)`.  Es una función estándar unix (requiere `#include<libgen.h>`. Por el aspecto de la ruta deduzco que trabajas en Windows, pero no sé con qué compilador de C. Cabe suponer que tu biblioteca estándar C esté adaptada también a Windows y sepa parsear correctamente las rutas que usan \ en lugar de `/`.

Comment: Estoy usando mingw bajo windows, por lo que basename no me sirve.
Hago un do while para recorrer desde el final hasta la primera \ que aparezca.
Si luego imprimo la cadena caracter a caracter me sale bien, pero quiero tratarla para poder imprimirla desde un printf, no caracter a caracter. Gracias

Comment: En definitiva, me interesaria saber como imprimir una cadena con printf si dicha cadena ha sido rellenada caracter a caracter. Como dije antes, no se si es por el terminador nulo o no.  Gracias de nuevo

Comment: No me manejo aún con punteros, seguro que hay otra opción para, de momento, no usarlos

Comment: @Rodrigo los problemas que estás teniendo para comentar son porque estás usando credenciales de un usuario diferente al que usaste en la pregunta.. Podés ahorrarte problemas registrando un usuario

Answer (score 2):

Ya había respondido en un comentario, pero aparentemente ha pasado desapercibido, de modo que lo repito aquí.

El código de la pregunta es básicamente correcto (aunque podría hacerse de otras formas), salvo por el detalle de que parece suponer que el índice del primer carácter de una cadena es el 1, por ejemplo en líneas como:

```
    cantidad=1;
```

o

```
    i=1;
```

cuando en realidad los arrays en C comienzan en 0 (lo que incluye las cadenas, que no dejan de ser arrays de caracteres).

La razón por la que no te salía nada al imprimir, es que si usas 1 como índice inicial estás copiando la cadena una posición más allá de donde debería, y en su posición 0 no has escrito nada, por lo que dejas allí lo que hubiera inicialmente. Y lo que hay incialmente es un terminador de cadena, dado que `char nombrefich[50]="";` inicializa el array con una cadena vacía, es decir, con un terminador en su primera posición.

Es decir. Antes de ejecutar tus bucles, el array `nombrefich[]` contiene:

```
Indice     -> | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| ...
              +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
Contenido  -> |\0 | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ...
              +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
```

donde `?` representa cualquier caracter que nos es desconocido, y `\0` es el terminador de cadena. Tras ejecutar tus bucles, el array `nombrefich[]` contendrá:

```
Indice     -> | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| ...
              +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
Contenido  -> |\0 | r | e | s | u | l | . | e | x | e | \0| ? | ? | ...
              +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
```

Cuando le pides a `printf()` que imprima esa cadena (con `%s`), ya que lo primero que encuentra es el terminador `\0`, se detiene ahi sin imprimir nada más.

La solución, naturalmente, es inicializar `i` con 0 en lugar de 1. La variable `cantidad` no se usa aparentemente para nada, por lo que puede eliminarse, como ha señalado @NaCl en un comentario.

Comment: Si te fijas, la variable cantidad solo se define, se asigna y se incrementa en el bucle, pero luego de ahí no hace más nada, mi sugerencia para con esa variable es eliminarla si no tiene ningún uso aparente.

Comment: @NaCl Tienes razón, he editado la respuesta.